# WebApi2. How refer to the methods HttpPost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Help me please.
In my project I have no any Views. I need to test my method POST -  PostBook. How can I do this?
I tried to write url request but can acces only in method Get - GetAllUsers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3WMn.jpg)

Comment: You could use Postman, very good tool for testing APIs https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Answer (score 1):

The Fiddler tool will be helpfull :
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

It contains a request composer, you can use it to create a request using a GET or POST verb.

[image]

Comment: How should I make a request if I have routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",   - http://localhost:59039/PostBook?T